# VBA Excel code for erasing a range Error

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code which I am trying to run:-

```
Sub EraseRange()
 Dim UserRange As Range

 Set UserRange = Application.InputBox( _
  "Range to Erase", _
  "Range Erase", _
  Selection.Address, _
  8)

 UserRange.Clear
 UserRange.Select
End Sub
```

It's raising a runtime error:
****Runtime Error '424'
Object Required****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line:

```
Set UserRange = Application.InputBox( _
  "Range to Erase", _
  "Range Erase", _
  Selection.Address, _
  8)
```

With:

```
Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range to Erase", _
   Title:="Range Erase", Type:=8)
```

Note: there is little use of `UserRange.Select` once you already selected it through the `InputBox`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Could you please tell me what the problem was?

Comment: @HimanshuSingh  You don't need the third parameter `Selection.Address` when using `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=8`, it already states you expect to get a `Range` as an Input. Anyway, `Selection.Address` returns a `String` not a `Range`